# which module of floodlight does routing?

Tags: sdn

I recently started working with floodlight controller. Floodlight use Dijkstra algorithm to obtain a route between source and destination. I want to know which module of floodlight does routing and Dijkstra algorithm is in which java file of the module?
I want to modify it’s Dijkstra algorithm in my project.
Thanks

Comment: I am also new to floodlight. I am also looking solution to your problem. Check these files. Still i do not understand how to utilize these files for my own project. If you find a clue then inform me. Reference: 1. https://github.com/floodlight/floodlight/blob/master/src/main/java/net/floodlightcontroller/topology/TopologyManager.java
2. https://github.com/floodlight/floodlight/blob/master/src/main/java/net/floodlightcontroller/topology/TopologyInstance.java